# Count Value For Conditionals

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to count the number of instances in which the logged in users ID exists in the table AUTHORIZED_USERS. The value I'm looking for is found in the UNAME field and is a string that contains the following format: COMPANYNAME\111222333. If the value exists in the table, that means that user has permission to access the application/view. Otherwise, they get redirected to an access denied page. My code below is close to working, but gives the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near '\601011307'.
```

\601011307 is part of an entry contained in the tables UNAME field. The full value it should be identifying is COMPANYNAME\601011307.

How can I prevent this error and have the count value assigned to a variable so I can use it in conditionals?

```
 public ActionResult HolidayDateTable()
    {
        string whoareyoupeople = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string myerrorstring = "User " + whoareyoupeople + " attempted unauthorized access on " + date + ".";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        {
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUTHORIZED_USERS WHERE UNAME = "+whoareyoupeople+")");

            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE);
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Use a parameterized query

Comment: I see Entity Framework in your connection string. Are you actually using EF in your application? If so there is a much cleaner way to do that with LINQ

Comment: If you absolutely have to build up your SQL like that, then you are missing quotes around the username parameter.

Comment: And be warned, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection.

Comment: That's "SQL Injection **Attacks**" - your code is not secure.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Since a lot of people is suggesting you best practices, here is mine:

- You are hard-coding the ConnectionString. Use the connectionString section from the Web.config file;
- Consider using an ORM like Entity Framework;
- Move away your Data logic from the Controller;
- Consider using the Repository Pattern;
- Create an ActionFilter to avoid repeating your code for every restricted page;
- Configure the 403 page in the <customError> section from your Web.config and set the statusCode of the page to 403 when the user is not allowed to continue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to remove the right paranthesis and wrap it in single quotation marks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUTHORIZED_USERS WHERE UNAME = '" + whoareyoupeople + "'";
```

But you should really use sql-parameters instead to prevent sql-injection.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUTHORIZED_USERS WHERE UNAME = @UNAME 
// ...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = whoareyoupeople;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes to enclose the literal string-

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUTHORIZED_USERS WHERE UNAME = '"+whoareyoupeople+"'");
```

Comment: Adding quotes resolves one problem but doesn't solve the Sql Injection

Comment: That depends on whether `User.Identity.Name` is at risk of being manipulated. Although I agree, in principle, with using SQL Parameters only.